# Why does fixing the background to avoid scrolling breaks the mix-blend-mode css effect? Chrome only

Tags: css, mix-blend-mode

I found something weird while playing with `mix-blend-mode`. When I fix the background image, the `mix-blend-mode` effect doesn't work. This is happening in Chrome. But in Firefox it works fine. This is a bummer because I use parallax a lot. Any idea why is this happening or how to get around it so that I can fix the background and still use `mix-blend-mode`?

p.s. remove the `fixed` from here --> `background: url(http://unsplash.it/3200/1600?image=973) no-repeat no-repeat center center fixed;` and you'll see it work fine. Except, the background moves with the scroll :(

Here is an example:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-4"><h1 class="effect2">BRAZIL</h1></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-4"><h1 class="effect1">BRAZIL</h1></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-4"><h1 class="effect4">BRAZIL</h1></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-4"><h1 class="effect5">BRAZIL</h1></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-4"><h1 class="effect6">BRAZIL</h1></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-4"><h1 class="effect7">BRAZIL</h1></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-4"><h1 class="effect8">BRAZIL</h1></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-4"><h1 class="effect9">BRAZIL</h1></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-4"><h1 class="effect10">BRAZIL</h1></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-4"><h1 class="effect11">BRAZIL</h1></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-4"><h1 class="effect12">BRAZIL</h1></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-4"><h1 class="effect13">BRAZIL</h1></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-4"><h1 class="effect14">BRAZIL</h1></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-4"><h1 class="effect15">BRAZIL</h1></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-4"><h1 class="effect16">BRAZIL</h1></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-4"><h1 class="effect17">BRAZIL</h1></div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:900);
*{
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  background: url(http://unsplash.it/3200/1600?image=973) no-repeat no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height:100%;
}
h1 {
  font-family: raleway, sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 75px;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
}

.effect2{ mix-blend-mode: normal;}
.effect1{ mix-blend-mode: multiply;}
.effect4{ mix-blend-mode: screen;}
.effect5{ mix-blend-mode: overlay;}
.effect6{ mix-blend-mode: darken;}
.effect7{ mix-blend-mode: lighten;}
.effect8{ mix-blend-mode: color-dodge;}
.effect9{ mix-blend-mode: color-burn;}
.effect10{ mix-blend-mode: hard-light;}
.effect11{ mix-blend-mode: soft-light;}
.effect12{ mix-blend-mode: difference;}
.effect13{ mix-blend-mode: exclusion;}
.effect14{ mix-blend-mode: hue;}
.effect15{ mix-blend-mode: saturation;}
.effect16{ mix-blend-mode: color;}
.effect17{ mix-blend-mode: luminosity;}
```

This is what I'm seeing: 
[image]

You can use this [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/dGKmKR?editors=1100)

Comment: The codepen is working for me...

Comment: You can't be serious. really? hmmmm.

Comment: Yup, what are you seeing?

Comment: Well, I tested on firefox and its fine there. so i'll have to edit my question

Comment: what browser are yo uusing?

Comment: I'm using Chrome, I'll have a look in the FF and IE

Comment: It's not working in IE 11 (latest version) and as you said, fine in FF

Comment: This is bugging me out now. Because you are seeing the desired effect, I'm not. What gives?

Comment: Chrome. And by the way, I wouldn't use that as an answer. Someone will downvote it and vote to close it because it's a comment, not an answer or solution. FYI ;)

Comment: Good point, I assumed you was using IE.  Latest version of Chrome?

Comment: yeah. I am using Mac OS. Not that it would matter.

Comment: Safari is fine too. ugh

Comment: Can you apply GPU acceleration to chrome on mac?

Comment: not sure what that is. now, thats a possible solution! Suggest it as an answer and I'll try it out. If it works, You get yor answer marked

Comment: Please explain in detail or steps. That's how you get more votes ;)

Comment: Sorry, could you tell me if this works? http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/dGKmKR?editors=1100

Comment: I'd like to say there is no issue with your code, more the browser but i am trying some things

Comment: A little off topic but if you navigate to this site http://themes.3rdwavemedia.com/atom/ which of the two images do you see from this link? https://gyazo.com/f2ef8046d411827a4d71ac640606d6d0

Comment: the top one. How does this help?

Comment: There was a recent version of Chrome which had issues with `mix-blend-mode` and if you has the bottom image, you would have been on that build.  My simplest suggestion would be to reinstall chrome, as its working for me on specific version number

>Version 48.0.2564.97 m

Comment: ah, you may be unto something now. this is my version 47.0.2526.111 (64-bit)...I'll update

Comment: updated chrome. emptied cache. didn't fix it :(

Comment: Same version as mine? I know its anal and may not work but clean install chrome

Comment: I got it work in latest chrome by adding the background image to .container-fluid instead of body. Why I cannot say.

.container-fluid {
      background: url(http://unsplash.it/3200/1600?image=973) fixed;
      background-size: cover;
 }

Comment: @stubben Essentially that is where it will be implemented eventually. I just added it to the body for testing purposses and happened to notice that it wouldn't work. So...mayhaps, this has something to do with the body?